# Spring Cloud with Consul for High Availability

Tags: docker, spring-cloud, consul

I have a setup where I am deploying a spring-cloud-consul application from within a docker swarm overlay network.  In my overlay network I have created consul images on each node. When I spin up the spring-cloud-consul application I have to specify the host name of the consul agent it should talk to such as "discovery" so it can advertise itself and query for service discovery.  The issue here is that every container then is querying the same consul agent.  When I remove this particular consul agent the Ribbon DiscoveryClient seems to rely on its own cache rather than use one of the other consul nodes.

What is the proper way of starting up a micro service application using spring-cloud-consul and consul such that they are not reliant on one fixed consul agent.

Solutions I have thought of trying:

1. Having multiple compose files and which specify different consul agents.
2. Somehow having the docker image identify the node it is on and then set itself to use the consul agent local to that node.  (Not sure how to accomplish this yet.)
3. Package a consul agent with the spring-boot application.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: From https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/basics.html "The agent must run on every node that is part of a Consul cluster." IMO, running an agent on each node, is running an agent in each docker container.

Comment: That would be option 3.  But I feel like that is kind of breaking micro service encapsulation.  It also makes packaging these images harder as that would require extending the consul image, ensuring the java requirements for spring are there and then running both services.  It does however provide the highest reliability in that a given consul agent going down brings down only one instance.

Comment: What does "micro service encapsulation" mean? Consul is a single binary.

Comment: By encapsulation here I am referring to having two services running in a single container.  In this case both consul and the java spring executable.  In this case, however, the consul agent is providing a service to only the java spring application so perhaps it isn't a problem.  I am going to go test this approach of putting consul and the java executable in the same container. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I'm unsure why it's not ok to have both processes in a container.

Comment: @Bryan some source on the web (sorry to lazy to go looking now) made the point that one should not get to hung up on the "one process, one container" idea. Rather look at the **functionality the container is ultimately exposing** - that should be focused on "one domain".If you need supporting processed behind that on the same container - so what?

Comment: I have a related issue - my consul cluster is unable to reach the services for a health check. I believe I'm hitting the ["wrong NIC issue"](http://developerblog.info/2015/11/16/splendors-and-miseries-of-docker-network/) - any body have a quick pointer to get around that? or should I create a new SO issue?

Answer (score 0):

The consul agent must run on every node in the cluster. It is not necessary to run the consul agent inside every docker container, just on every node. You have the choice of installing the consul agent on every node, or running the consul agent in a docker container on every node.

For the consul agent in a docker container solution you will need to ensure you have the consul agent container running before other containers are started.

For details on running the consul agent in client mode in a docker container see: https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/ and search for Running Consul Agent in Client Mode. This defines the agent container with --net=host networking, so the agent behaves like it is installed natively, when it is actually in a docker container.